# Python - INSERT table INTO SQLite from MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlite, odbc

I am trying to query MS SQL Server for a table.column, then insert this output into a sqlite table.

This example has one numeric column in the SQL Server source table.
I think I've almost got it by scouring the other answers.

Please let me know what I am missing.

```
import sqlite3
import pyodbc


#def connect_msss():
ODBC_Prod = ODBC_Prod 
SQLSN = SQLSN 
SQLpass = SQLpass 
conn_str = ('DSN='+ODBC_Prod+';UID='+SQLSN+';PWD='+SQLpass)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)


#def connect_sqlite():
sl3Conn = sqlite3.connect('server_test.db')
c = sl3Conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mrn_test (PTMRN NUMERIC)')


#def query_msss():

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT TOP 50 PTMRN FROM dbo.atl_1234_mrntest")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO mrn_test VALUES (?)", row)
conn.commit()


#connect_msss()
#connect_sqlite()
#query_msss()
```

Error 1:

> c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mrn_test
>   (PTMRN NUMERIC)')

```
 Out[117]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x2d1a742fc70>
```

Error 2:

> cur = conn.cursor() cur.execute("SELECT TOP 50 PTMRN FROM
>   dbo.atl_1234_mrntest")

```
Out[118]: <pyodbc.Cursor at 0x2d1a731b990>
```

Comment: Those functions could not possibly run without error. For example, in `query_msss` neither `c` nor `conn` are defined.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I edited the question with a simplified code and the errors.

Comment: if there are errors, what are the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not committing the executed changes on the sqlite connection, after the `c.execute` step you're committing the MySQL DB connection.  I think you need to replace `conn.commit()` at the end with `sl3Conn.commit()`.

Comment: perfect, that was it, thank you! By the way, those output messages that I've called "error messages" in the question - do you know their relevance or significance?